# Ошибка при освобождении памяти, но не при выходе за границы массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Когда захожу за границу массива, то не получаю ошибку, но если пытаюсь удалить по указателю, то программа падает. Почему?

```
int main()
{
    int * p = new int[5];
    p[10] = 5;
    delete [] p;
}
```

Comment: после `p[10] = 5;` программа может вести себя как ей захочется, это называется UB. Упасть, соответственно, может в произвольный момент времени.

Comment: *"но не при выходе за границы массива"* -- и это вы пишете, собственноручно выйдя за эти самые границы???

Comment: @PinkTux: Думаю, ТС имел в виду, что _падает_ не во время выхода за границы.

Comment: Cи не контролирует за вас ваши действия. никаких проверок выхода за границы нет. Вы просто затираете какую то область памяти, а что из за этого произойдет предсказать невозможно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете портить *служебную информацию* менеджера памяти, только и всего. В результате диспетчер памяти не в состоянии корректно освободить память, и система рушится.

Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное :). Кстати, рекомендую книгу [Безопасное программирование на C и C++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1908-3.html) - там об этом (некорректной работе с памятью, которая может оказаться уязвимостью) много рассказывается.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что неопределенное поведение, которое возникает при записи вне пределов выделенной памяти может проявляться совершенно по-разному. В том числе и на более поздних операциях. В этом вся суть UB (Undefined Behaviour).